# ruby pick (select) indices from collection

Tags: ruby, enumerable

I have an array `a`. I want to build a new array with one or more of its elements picked out. The resulting array should look like:

```
 [a[5], a[7], a[8]]
```

How can I do this selection by passing the array of indices `[5,7,8]`? I imagined something like:

```
 b = a.select([5,7,8])
```

which doesn't work; `select` needs a block to evaluate. I could enumerate over the array and pick manually, but I have the feeling this should be possible more elegantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Array#values_at`.

```
b = a.values_at(*[5,7,8])
```